# how to migrate data from old server to new server proper way

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have millions of records from dozens of tables,

I want to modify, remove, transform certain records or table structure,

then newly transformed DB to be transferred to another server with downtime of 6 hours..

**My current idea:**

- temporarily spin up high-performance VPS (migration server)
- connect with the old DB
- run transformation using laravel queue
- and store the transformed data to (migration server)
- dump the .sql
- and import into new server

how was my idea? or is there a better way? tq

Comment: Take a look at ETL tools on Google. These are tools built for the exact purpose of migrating (large) databases. I've personally used RapidMiner for a project and it worked perfectly for my usecase.

Comment: using ETL tools kinda not an option, the use case is too complex @Bodhi

Comment: @Vortechron complex cases are what ETL tool are for.

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch around in the cloud, why do you need 6 hours?  It seems like everything would be done on a single server.  The downtime would not be in switching servers, but in doing incompatible upgrades to the schema.

I would spin off a copy of the dataset, practice the migration on the new copy.  Possibly this would not need a higher performance server.  Repeat until satisfied with the process.

In doing so, you will discover how long the migration takes.

Then...  Go offline; do the migration on the production server; drop old databases; come back online.

Even before that, I would see if some of the steps could be done with zero downtime.  One technique that I like, though it is complex:

Change app to handle both old and new schema; change schema; cleanup code.  (This is especially handy if there are multiple app and/or database servers.  Sounds like you are not at that scale.)

Be aware of what schema changes are fast and what are slow.

As for dump and reload...  When I have the luxury of it, it is a lot easier to do things like `INSERT INTO new_db.t SELECT .. FROM old_db.t` on a single instance.